# Keeping the constant part of a URL as a variable available to all view controllers

Tags: swift

I am currently expressing JSON data by loading the information from a URL, the URL is from an API that comes in two forms:

`test.example.com` and `example.com`

Full links throughout the applications will always end differently after the forward slash:

`test.example.com/example1` ... `test.example.com/example2`

But the beginning will always be one of the 2 forms above

I would like to the ability to easily switch between the two URL by changing it in one place using perhaps an extension that is available for all view controller.

**So for example I have:**

```
private func JSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://test.example.com/example"),
        let sample = value1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "example1=\(example)".data(using: .utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            self.JStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode([exampleStruct].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {

            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

What would be the best approach for switching between the two urls?

**UPDATE:**

**Is it wrong to just use:**

```
struct URLVar {
    static var url = "https://example1.com/example/"
}
```

and reference URLVar.url when needed?

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is maintain an api.plist file (a key value file store) and an environment.plist file. The ending part of the APIs will be stored in the api.plist, while the domain parts `example.com` will be stored in the environment.plist.

Note that this way, I can have multiple environment.plist files pointing to different places (a production server, a staging server, etc...). I can simply switch in the necessary environment.plist using a build script phase.

To read, I use the normal plist reading mechanisms provided by apple and combine the domainUrl (in environment.plist) with the required resource path (in api.plist). The following link will explore reading options for you:
https://learnappmaking.com/plist-property-list-swift-how-to/

You can also look at the following library that adds some beautiful code generation capabilities for .plist files among others:
https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen

Comment: I see, would it entirely incorrect to just use a struct variable as shown in my update?

Comment: It's all about how you want to architect your app. While your way certainly works (I think SwitGen internally generates the same for you), it wont be flexible enough to generate different builds for different schemes (you will have to change code). In most applications, such external information are placed in configuration files separate from actual code.